# Error executing code: Wrong type of argument for conversion function

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I am getting this error while Deserializing an object in AX. To make it more weird its fine in my local but failing in other.

str sampleString = conpeek(nodeData, 1);

JArray jArray = JsonConvert::DeserializeObject(sampleString );

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue. I don't know if your issue is the same as mine, but in my case, it was coming from an attempt to grab a boolean value from a deserialized container. It would work when running from the AX client, but didn't work when running from CIL. (CLR stuff sometimes behaves differently running locally vs on the server in CIL.) Solved the issue by grabbing the value as a string, then converting to boolean.